Unreal Engine 5: packagingresults: error: unknown error
Alright y'all, so here's the issue: I have finished creating my game in Unreal Engine 5.4, and as I Build All Levels, and then Cook Content, I am ready to Package Project (I did get a couple of Warnings, while Building, saying that the Sky Sphere has no collision or something). Anyways, after a few seconds, the Packaging Fails and all the Output Log shows as an error is: PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error. Well now that ain't exactly too specific, is it? Oh yeah, I should probably specify that the Project uses Metahumans, and therefore the Metahuman Plugin.
I have tried:

Disabling the Metahuman Plugin

Including the Game Maps in the Packaging Project Settings (Reads: List of Maps to Include in a Packaged Build)

Creating a Plugins Folder in the Project Folder in my PC Library and Pasting the "Marketplace" Folder (You can Find it at: "\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Plugins". You should see the Marketplace Folder)

Copying the "hostfxr.dll" file from: "\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Binaries\ThirdParty\DotNet\6.0.302\windows\host\fxr\6.0.7" and then Pasting it inside the AutomationTool and UnrealBuildTool Folders (\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Binaries\DotNET)

Downloading Windows SDK and .NET (I have no idea what they do, but some people said it would work. Not for me)

Finding any Extra .cpp files in the Game's folder in my Library and then "\Intermediate\Source", but all I found was: Game.Build, Game.cpp Game.Target, GameClient.Target, GameEditor.Target, GameServer.Target.

Changing the Project Icon to an Older Exported Game's Icon


Here's the thing: The last thing seemed to Work for a bit, but since it wasn't the actual icon I wanted to use, I Cancelled the Packaging, trying to Re-Export the Official Icon. When I switched to that, the pakcaging failed again. I switch back to the other game's icon, that originally worked, but this time that failed too!
NOTE: My SSD doesn't have much free space and the Unreal Editor sends warnings about low space whenever I open it. But I don't think that's what causes the issue, because when I tried to package the previous game, I didn't get an issue.
Output Log: AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=6 (6) UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): BUILD FAILED
PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error
Guys, I would really appreciate any help I can get here, cause none of my actions seem to change anything
Thanks,
Alex Ker

It's hard to say what's happening here, it would be great if you've attached a log output, at least last few dozens of lines. From my experience, Unknown Error usually happens during cooking phase, and usually means error in content setup, so if you fix all cooking errors / warning, most likely, the error will get gone.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
